# Cant compile code with AzureIoTHub library on NodeMcu v3 (ESP8266) in Visual Code with Platformio

Tags: esp8266, azure-iot-hub, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, platformio

I'm working with Visual Studio Code, Platformio extension, Arduino framework. Have NodeMCU v3 board with ESP8266. 
I wrote some simple program, which gets data from sensor and blinks some LED. Everythink went fine, code compiled and worked on the nodeMCU. 
Great, so as a next step I wanted to connect it to Azure. So as multiple examples were showing, I included some libraries and wrote/copied simple code. After removing some first compilation errors:

- missing blob.h -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino/issues/101
- error in Arduino.h, round(x) -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino#simple-sample-instructions
- MQTT_Protocol' was not declared -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino/issues/108

I've stucked with another error. After cutting code down, you can see a very easy code here:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "config.h"

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <AzureIoTHub.h>
#include <AzureIoTProtocol_MQTT.h>
#include <AzureIoTUtility.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include "iothubtransportmqtt.h"

static IOTHUB_CLIENT_LL_HANDLE iotHubClientHandle;

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN_GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PIN_GREEN_LED, LOW);

  static IOTHUB_CLIENT_TRANSPORT_PROVIDER protocol = MQTT_Protocol;
  iotHubClientHandle = IoTHubClient_LL_CreateFromConnectionString("connectionString", protocol);  
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(PIN_GREEN_LED, LOW);
}
```

Without calling IoTHubClient_LL_CreateFromConnectionString function, which I guess can't be skipped to make connection to Azure IoT Hub, code builds. I had to add iothubtransportmqtt.h, so the MQTT_Protocol is available.

My platformio.ini file (changing the board to esp12e makes no difference):

```
[env:nodemcuv2]
platform = espressif8266
board = nodemcuv2
framework = arduino
lib_deps =
    DHT
    AzureIoTHub
    ArduinoJson
```

This is how the build starts:

```
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif8266/nodemcuv2.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 8266 2.5.1 > NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module) [or Espressif ESP8266 ESP-12E for esp12e board]
HARDWARE: ESP8266 80MHz, 80KB RAM, 4MB Flash
PACKAGES:
 - framework-arduinoespressif8266 3.20701.0 (2.7.1)
 - tool-esptool 1.413.0 (4.13)
 - tool-esptoolpy 1.20800.0 (2.8.0)
 - toolchain-xtensa 2.40802.200502 (4.8.2)
```

Dependency:

```
Dependency Graph
DHT 1.0.0
AzureIoTHub 1.3.8
AzureIoTUtility 1.3.8.1
ESP8266WiFi 1.0
ArduinoJson 6.15.2
AzureIoTProtocol_MQTT 1.3.8
```

Here the terminal output with dozens of warnings before:

Linking .pio\build\nodemcuv2\firmware.elf
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o):(.text.initialize_iothub_client+0x6c): undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o):(.text.initialize_iothub_client+0x78): undefined reference to`IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Create'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `initialize_iothub_client':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text.initialize_iothub_client+0x1de): undefined reference to`IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text.initialize_iothub_client+0x3ea): undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Create'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text.initialize_iothub_client+0x486): undefined reference to`IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text.initialize_iothub_client+0x547): undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o):(.text.mqtt_operation_complete_callback+0x20): undefined 
reference to`retry_control_reset'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o): in function `mqtt_operation_complete_callback':
iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c:(.text.mqtt_operation_complete_callback+0xd3): undefined reference to`retry_control_reset'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o):(.text.free_transport_handle_data+0x0): undefined reference to `retry_control_destroy'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o):(.text.free_transport_handle_data+0x1f): undefined reference to`retry_control_destroy'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o):(.text.IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_SetRetryPolicy+0x8): undefined reference to `retry_control_create'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o): in function`IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_SetRetryPolicy':
iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c:(.text.IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_SetRetryPolicy+0x37): undefined reference to `retry_control_create'

c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c:(.text.IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_SetRetryPolicy+0x60): undefined reference to`retry_control_destroy'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o): in function `IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_Create':

iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c:(.text.IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_Create+0x1ae): undefined reference to`retry_control_create'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o):(.text.IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_DoWork+0x64): undefined reference to `retry_control_should_retry'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o):(.text.IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_DoWork+0xca): undefined reference to`retry_control_should_retry'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o):(.text.IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_SetOption+0x50): undefined reference to `retry_control_set_option'
c:/users/mmielnic/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib1b2\libAzureIoTHub_ID480.a(iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c.o): in function`IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_SetOption':
iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c:(.text.IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_SetOption+0x192): undefined reference to `retry_control_set_option'
**collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
*** [.pio\build\nodemcuv2\firmware.elf] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

I've found a reason of that issue. I did not resolve previous problem with lack of blob.h file corectly. The workaround with adding new parameters to platform.txt did not work, So I had to modify file iothub_client_ll_uploadtoblob.c manually by removing:
 #include "internal/blob.h" line of code and all it affected there.

The second problem was, that there was file missing: iothub_client_retry_control.c for nodemcuv2 environment. I do not know why it wasn't there, but I used file from esp12e env, so simply copied:
.pio\libdeps\esp12e\AzureIoTHub_ID480\src\iothub_client_retry_control.c
to
.pio\libdeps\nodemcuv2\AzureIoTHub_ID480\src\iothub_client_retry_control.c

After that, code compiled and I was able to connect to wifi and send messages to the Azure ioT Hub.

Hope it helps to someone.

Comment: Glad that you have found the root cause, could you please mark your response as 'Answer', which could help others.